# Alignment issues in iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, avplayer, iphone-x

In my application i have a screen which contains close button on top and program information at bottom and both trailing,leading,bottom and top constraints related to safe area.

Button width and height is 1:1. Program info area height is 0.25 of view height. In run time adding avplayerviewcontroller view on screen whose height is 75% of self.view.It's working fine in all device except iPhone X. If i launch app in landscape then alignment is fine and if I change orientation I can see 44 pixels as x value. If I launch app in portrait first then portrait orientation values are correct if I change orientation to landscape then 44 pixels top(y) value is adding. I am not getting how to fix this issue. Please guide me.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Please try to set a fixed value for your Program info height. (replace 25% by 260px for example).

Comment: Hi Gregory it's not helping me. Frame is changing like this po self->livePlayer.contentOverlayView.frame (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 812, height = 375)) (lldb) po placeHolder.frame (origin = (x = 0, y = 44), size = (width = 812, height = 297)) (lldb) po containerView.frame (origin = (x = 0, y = 44), size = (width = 812, height = 297))

Comment: Extra 44 pixels are getting added when change orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you have defined constraints in percentages, which might be an issue. When you rotate the screen the mid section might be too small. Have you tried the rotated layout in interface builder to see what is happening? Defining layouts with constraints is relatively easy in interface builder and you can test the layouts as well.

If you programmatically set the constraints, it is hard to find out where it went wrong. If you have one ambiguous constraint, the whole screen can be weird.

If you need to make programmatically set constraints, you should make a test setup in interface builder and implement the good setting in the program code, when everything works as planned.

I have checked your storyboard and I think the issue might be that you have two safe area defined. One outside the containerview and one inside. What you put inside the container view, might be wrongly calculating the constraints inside.

[image]

Try to take out this checkbox and try it again.

Comment: In interface builder (storyboard) i checked in all orientations it's working fine not in device or in simulator.

Comment: Could you upload your project? If not secret? Or just the storyboard file?

Comment: Hi Endre how to send storyboard.

Comment: I updated my question with viewwill transition code.

Comment: Frame is changing like this po self->livePlayer.contentOverlayView.frame
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 812, height = 375))

(lldb) po placeHolder.frame
(origin = (x = 0, y = 44), size = (width = 812, height = 297))

(lldb) po containerView.frame
(origin = (x = 0, y = 44), size = (width = 812, height = 297))

Comment: Why that 44 pixels are adding when change orientation pls let me know.

Comment: Hi Endre should i need account in box.com to share storyboard? please let me know.

Comment: Shall i send a mail Endre.

Comment: Than send it to my iCloud account. endre_olah@me.com. I will check it and give you my thoughts.

Comment: Hi Endhre sorry to say i am unable send. Shall i send from my gmail account?

Comment: Hi Endre i sent pls check once. It very imp to me it blocks my work.

Comment: Hi did you send it somehow? You can share via google drive too. my gmail address is endreolah68@gmail.com.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Which view is not working properly? What I see is that on the iPhoneX the 44 value is exactly a safe area value for x or y origin, depending on the orientation. So when you rotate the phone this might be the adder on X or Y. Try to change the constraints from safearea guides to fullscreen and manually handle the safe constraints. Or calculate in these values.